# Busting Chrome cache for browser-sync reloads

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flask, webpack, browser-sync

I have browser-sync working OK, but I am still having a hard time with the caching of the previous html.  Even with Chrome's "disable cache" checked, and even in incognito mode!

To get page changes to load I *always* have to "Clear Cache and Hard Reload".

I'm wondering, is it possible to have browser-sync reload the same url but with a hash  as a query parameter?  Like:

https://my.flask.com/?q=jsd094334jn3io482048
(with a different hash each time)

My particular setup is I'm developing a flask app on a local domain: https://my.flask.com/ with a self-signed certificate.  I am not using a port because I am trying to mimic production in every possible way.

I'm using browser-sync via the `browser-sync-webpack-plugin` and a script at the bottom of the page(s):

```
<script id="__bs_script__">
  document.write("<script async src='https://HOST:3060/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.24.4'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
</script>
```

The hot reloading on changes works as it should both in webpack and browser-sync.  The assets loaded by the webpage (css, js) are hashed (or fingerprinted or whatever), so they are set up to bypass the cache on changes.  SO they are not the issue.

I can't figure out why reloads of / and /[route] are getting cached, and how to bypass it!

Any help appreciated

**UPDATE**

My best guess at this point is that the problem isn't the cache - it's that browser-sync is triggering a refresh before the webpack build is completely finished.

Comment: With disabled cache, Chrome should not cache anything. Take a look into dev console and tell what status you see there for files that do not change -- if it is 200, then requests are cached on your server.

Comment: I think you're right. The problem is intermittent.  Sometimes it reloads with the changes, sometimes not.  My best guess at this point is that the reload is triggering before the webpack build is completely finished.

Comment: where did you add reloadDleay? I am having the same issue, but when developer tools is open and disabled cache checked, works perfect, it reloads after every change. As soon as I close dev tools it stops refreshing changes. I am assuming because disable cache in the dev tools only work if the dev tools are open.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was not the cache, it was that browsersync was triggering a refresh before the webpack build was done.  Adding `reloadDelay: 500` has helped